# Import other submodules & ignore standard lib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating some module `GUI` (describing a graphical interface) which requires another module `somecalc` (doing some calculations). The latter imports standard libraries: `os`, `sys`, `time`, etc.

The objective is to build a package in the end.

**I cannot find the conventions regarding importing other submodules within a package and/or other self-developed modules:**

1. without cluttering the name space (and autocompletion in Ipython):

   - I don't want to see `somecalc.os`, `somecalc.sys`, `somecalc.time`
2. without having to re-import standard libraries that were already imported in `somecalc`

   - even if I fix issue #1 by writting `import os as _os` in `somecalc.py`, I have two ways of doing the same. If I do the following tests within `GUI`:
   - `somecalc.os is os #TRUE` (with `import os` in `somecalc.py`)
   - `somecalc._os is os #TRUE` (no auto completion from IPython with `import os as _os` in `somecalc.py`)
3. without cumbersome calls to standard library, e.g. write `somecalc.os.listdir` when I simply could write `os.listdir`. Besides I don't believe it is clear if other developers will work on the project with me.

I know that once I want to turn my folder into a package I am advised to add a `__init__.py` file with all my imports. But when I'm developing/debugging my submodules (using code below `if __name__ = '__main__'`), the `__init__.py` file in the root directory is ignored. Besides I still need to write `import somecalc` at the beginning of my `GUI.py` file.

What are the conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__init__.py` only expose what you need to expose. Create other `.py` that requires the standard librairies, and import what you need.

```
$ tree GUI/
GUI
├── __init__.py
└── somecalc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── somecalc.py

$ cat GUI/__init__.py
import somecalc

$ cat GUI/somecalc/__init__.py
from somecalc import get_time

$ cat GUI/somecalc/somecalc
import os
import sys
import time

def get_time():
    return time.time()
```

That way, when you import `somecalc`, you only see `get_time` and the `somecalc` submodule:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, May 20 2015, 15:38:28) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import GUI
>>> dir(GUI)
[..., 'somecalc']
>>> dir(GUI.somecalc)
[..., 'get_time', 'somecalc']
>>> dir(GUI.somecalc.somecalc)
[..., 'get_time', 'os', 'sys', 'time']
>>>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't allow me to access the standard libraries from GUI, or in a more cumbersome way: now somecalc.os.listdir became somecalc.somecalc.os.listdir.

Comment: Access standard librairies with an `import sys` ? What is the problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is why I am asking the convention.
So even if a module "x" is already imported in a submodule "sm", I still must import "x" everytime in all modules already importing "sm" , right?
This is what I find strange as I have never found standard libraries under dir of downloaded modules.

Comment: It is normal to reimport module. When you reimport, the python interpreter will see that the module has already been loaded once, and wont reload it again. The module that you develop should not depend of other package dependencies.

Comment: I'm still surprised that I haven't found "os" or "sys" in the dir of frequently used libraries (like PyQt). Do they really import them with a leading underscore?

Comment: For instance with the popular `requests` module, inside the `requests/__init__.py` you will see that it imports every functions and classes (and nothing else). Standard libraries can be found in the modules files: `from requests.utils import os` inside `requests/utils.py` . The `__init__.py` file does not contains any declaration, only imports.

Comment: Thanks! Great example. I'll note your answer as correct, even if most info is in the comments  :)